# Erro ao executar um projeto react-native e firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native

Bom dia/madrugada, estou com o erro ao dar react-native run-android
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o código é este

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Text, View, Button} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component  {
    componentDidMount(){
        var config = {
            apiKey: "AIzaSyCrI-yOVMpn4SSzaAaiCmcZxPSsjS1mIYE",
            authDomain: "configuracaofirebasereac-1fcea.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://configuracaofirebasereac-1fcea.firebaseio.com",
            projectId: "configuracaofirebasereac-1fcea",
            storageBucket: "configuracaofirebasereac-1fcea.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "61563493608";
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(config)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>Olá Mundo</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
 }
```

e não consigo de jeito maneira arrumar, alguém por favor pode me dar uma ajuda?

Comment: Ao invés de colocar o código no componentDidMount, coloque no componentWillMount

Answer (score 0):

Amigo faça a seguinte alteração no seu código:

```
// import firebase from 'firebase';
import firebase from '@firebase/app'
```

Ou instale a versão 5.0.3, ou mais atual do firebase (recomendo usar o **yarn**).